# PHP 2nd while loop within a while loop only run once

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

need some expert help here on my php/mysql coding. My expectation for my while loop to check for every block and echo out all the users from the same block in 1 row by using the 2nd while loop to accomplished it. I managed to display it though but it won't display the other users from other blocks respectively.

Here is my code so far, i'm quite new to php though.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <table border='1'>
        <th>Block</th>
        <th>company</th>
        <th>Username</th>
        <th>datetime</th>
    <?php
    require('db.php');


    $sql = "
    SELECT block_directories.block, event_details.username, event_details.datetime, event_details.eventDate, companies.company, event_details.tag
    FROM block_directories INNER JOIN event_details
    ON block_directories.block_id = event_details.tag
    INNER JOIN companies
    ON event_details.company=companies.company_id"
    ;
    $records=mysql_query($sql);

    $sqlblock = "
    SELECT * FROM block_directories"
    ;
    $blockrecords=mysql_query($sqlblock);

    //while loop to echo all blocks into table ina column
    while($blkrecords=mysql_fetch_assoc($blockrecords)){    
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>{$blkrecords['block']}</td>";

        //while loop to echo all users within the same block
        while($users=mysql_fetch_assoc($records)){
            if($users['block']==$blkrecords['block']){
                echo "<td>{$users['company']}</td>";
                echo "<td>{$users['username']}</td>";
                echo "<td>{$users['datetime']}</td>";
            }
        }
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    ?>
    </table>
</body>
```

[Output Display of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ToeJD.png)

Comment: That's because you're inner looping to the end of the $records recordset in the first outer loop, but in the second outer loop, you're already at the end of the recordset, so it won't loop again unless you rewind that $records recordset using [mysql_data_seek](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-data-seek.php)

Comment: If it's not a problem try to use `mysqli` or `PDO`. `mysql` is deprecated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because `mysql_fetch_assoc()` doesn't return rows after it's pointer reaches end of the result set.

You will need to re point it to the first of the result set by adding following line.

```
mysql_data_seek($records, 0);
```

So your code of loops would something like this,

```
while($blkrecords=mysql_fetch_assoc($blockrecords)){    
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>{$blkrecords['block']}</td>";

        //while loop to echo all users within the same block
        while($users=mysql_fetch_assoc($records)){
            if($users['block']==$blkrecords['block']){
                echo "<td>{$users['company']}</td>";
                echo "<td>{$users['username']}</td>";
                echo "<td>{$users['datetime']}</td>";
            }
        }
        mysql_data_seek($records, 0);
        echo "</tr>";
    }
```

> mysql_* extensions were deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in
>   PHP 7.0.0. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.